# HPI 2.2 installation on Alfresco community version 5.0

Tags: integration, alfresco

Let me start with apology just in case this is the wrong place or irrelevant by any chance.

I m fairly new to Alfresco, it has only been a couple of weeks using Alfresco however, my interest in Alfresco is driven by my requirement for claims processing and I came across HPI 2.2 which is just a simplified extension into Alfresco, for more detail, please check out the link below

http://www.tsgrp.com/Open_Source/OpenContent/open-content-hpi.jsp

The instructions on tsg website is for the older version of Alfresco 4.2, I have Alfresco 5.0 community version installed, I managed to install the HPI in Alfresco however after the installation I can't login, I m assuming it has something to do with new war file created during HPI installation.

I would really appreciate if anyone has similar problem and figured out a solution, I will really appreciate the input and help.

Answer (score 1):

I would be shocked if TSG had already updated HPI to work with 4.2 because 5.0 has been out for only a week or so. Why not grab 4.2.f and use HPI with that? You don't want to be using 5.0 for anything serious this early anyway.